# creationTime, expiry, lastAccessed time of cookies

Tags: android, cookies, firefox-addon

I'm using nsICookie2 to get the existent cookies by a firefox for android extension. When I display the list of cookies and their attributes I noticed something very weird, the expiry time is always inferior to the creation and the last accessed time, exp:

```
    host.bluekai.com expires on 1393031459 time now 1377624200429 cookie creation time 1377479134953422 cookie lasAccessed 1377481998001732
```

and in my code i wrote this:

```
    " host"+coo.host+" expires on "+coo.expiry+" time now "+dd.getTime()+"  cookie creationTime   "+coo.creationTime+"   cookie lastAccessed   "+coo.lastAccessed+" \n";
```

Can anybody provide me a logical explanation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not. One is in seconds, the others in in microseconds, you you need to scale:

```
1393031459 > (1377624200429 / 1000)
```

nsICookie2:

```
/**
 * the actual expiry time of the cookie, in seconds
 * since midnight (00:00:00), January 1, 1970 UTC.
 *
 * this is distinct from nsICookie::expires, which
 * has different and obsolete semantics.
 */
readonly attribute int64_t expiry;

/**
 * the creation time of the cookie, in microseconds
 * since midnight (00:00:00), January 1, 1970 UTC.
 */
readonly attribute int64_t creationTime;

/**
 * the last time the cookie was accessed (i.e. created,
 * modified, or read by the server), in microseconds
 * since midnight (00:00:00), January 1, 1970 UTC.
 *
 * note that this time may be approximate.
 */
readonly attribute int64_t lastAccessed;
```

Admittedly, it is quite confusing to use different time units. :p

Comment: Now it makes sens, I didn't pay attention to the difference. Thanks nmaier.